# How capture a dynamic sub-path like "/COMPANY/rest..." with Suave and nest the routes?

Tags: f#, routes, suave

I have several routes that must be grouped by "company", plus some that are valid for all:

```
/login
/logout
/demo1/customers
/demo1/products
```

So I try with suave:

```
let doReqScan action =
     warbler (fun r ->
        LOG.Debug("ROUTE: {route}", r.request.url)
        match r.request |> getCompany with
        | Some(x) ->
            let isAuth, validDb = isValidDb(x)

            if validDb then
                if isAuth then
                    action(r.request) |> _DoSet
                else
                    jSonNoAuth
            else    
                never
        | _ -> never
    )

let doReq(route:string, action) =
    path route >=> doReqScan action  

let appCompany company =
    choose [      
      path "/ws" >=> handShake ws
      GET >=>  choose
        [
          doReq("/customers", (fun r -> queryCustomers(r)))
          pathScan "/customers/%d" (fun the_id -> doReqScan (fun r -> queryCustomer(r, the_id)))
        ]
     ]
let app =
  choose
    [ allow_cors
      pathScan "/%s" (fun company ->
       choose
            [
                appCompany company
                GET >=>  choose
                  [
                    _doReq( "/config", (fun r -> config(r)) )
                  ]
                POST >=> choose
                  [
                    _doReq( "/login", (fun r -> login(r)))
                    _doReq( "/logout", (fun r -> logout(r)))
                  ]
            ]
        )
      GET >=> Files.browseHome
      jSonNotFound
    ]
```

However the pathScan capture all the url "/demo1/customers" instead of only "/demo1".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

- All common urls are in the form: `/something`
- All company urls are in the form: `/companyName/something`

Then you can try this:

```
let appCompany company =
    let com x = "/" + company + x
    choose [      
        path (com "/ws") >=> handShake ws
        GET >=> choose [
            doReq(com "/customers", (fun r -> queryCustomers(r)))
            pathScan "/%s/customers/%d" (fun _ the_id -> doReqScan (fun r -> queryCustomer(r, the_id)))
        ]
    ]

let app =
    choose [
        allow_cors
        GET >=> choose [
                    _doReq( "/config", (fun r -> config(r)) )
                ]
        POST >=> choose [
                    _doReq( "/login", (fun r -> login(r)))
                    _doReq( "/logout", (fun r -> logout(r)))
                 ]
        pathScan "/%s/%s" (fun company _ -> appCompany company)
        GET >=> Files.browseHome
        jSonNotFound
    ]
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the idea. However appCompany will not match sub-paths like "/companyName/something". company get passed, but the pathScan/path not continue after it. I add more code to see the whole thing.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what is proposed in Giraffe documentation (similar to Suave in spirit). They use a pathScan with **all parts at once** named [subroutef](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#subroutef)

So it would be something like :

```
pathScan "/%s/customers" queryCustomers
pathScan "/%s/products" queryProducts
...
```